# Теория по виджету

Tags: java, android, теория, виджет

Интересует тема создания виджета для рабочего стола, который будет тесно связан с основным приложением. Может, кто-нибудь, посоветовать статьи, видеоролики или книги (где есть подобный раздел) на русском языке? Буду очень благодарен, т.к. обширных руководств по данной теме я не нашёл, а немногочисленные статьи датированы слишком далекими годами.

Comment: Вот свежая [статья](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/492166/) на хабре в которой достаточно подробно описан весь процесс создания виджета